# C# - Windows Form loaded with images on PictureBox : Can they be turned invisible or hidden into another color?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an image matching game in C#.

My idea was to load all the pictures when I create the form. Then, when I launch the program and the form loads, I wanted to turn all those icons to black, hiding the pictures.

I've tried changing `icon.BackColor = Color.Black` but it doesn't do anything. Setting the visibility to hidden is also not an option.

Is there a way, or do I need to load the pictures individually using `image.fromFile...` went he form loads?

EDIT : As I was not able to find a way to answer this question, I took another approach. simply loading only black colored pictureboxes, attributing a random assigned name to each of them corresponding to an image. And on click, this image is shown.

Comment: Why not model behavior after how it might work in the real world?  Show something akin to the back of a card such as a big question markl image, then when it is clicked 'turn it over' to show the actual image

Comment: What control do you use: Icon? PictureBox? You have the Visible flag as property, and you can also use the ImageList control so that you don't have to do "fromFile" on the fly, the pics are already in the memory with this control, and can meet @Nyssa's idea of the "back" side of the card.

Comment: I use PictureBox. Visible flag will just cause it to be completely blank, which is no longer clickable I guess? I thought then of adding another "black" icon image as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I was not able to find a way to answer this question, I took another approach. Simply loading only black-colored picture boxes, attributing a randomly assigned name to each of them corresponding to an image. And on click, this image is shown.